# How to fix file format when get it from linux server and sending it as txt format as attachment in mail?

Tags: linux, oracle, outlook, plsqldeveloper

I use PL/SQL oracle,
in procedure i write data in .txt file and i save it in directory that exists in linux server by using UTL_FILE library,
when i get the file from linux and send it as attachment in mail the format of file changed like below:
the file in linux contain data:

```
00005458563722650096252557
00028282778772626667677777
63767373883899999393999999
```

the file when i send it as attachment in mail the data be like this:

```
000054585637226500962525570002828277877262666767777763767373883899999393999999
```

In PLSQL Developer i do the following statments in procedure to create and write the data inside file:

```
DIRECTORY_NAME := 'folder'
FILENAME := 'file.txt'

ftype := UTL_FILE.open(DIRECTORY_NAME , FILENAME , 'W');

// loop for 
Loop
   FETCH Result
    INTO V_WRITE_TXT
   EXIT WHEN P_RESULT %NOTFOUND;
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(ftype , V_WRITE_TXT);
END LOOP;

UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(ftype);
```

Overview:
the format of txt file in linux is correct, but when send the file by email the format changing
the changes on format is merge the records in one line

Comment: How did you write this file on linux server? Please share the code you have used to write on server.

Comment: _MansiRaval I updated the Question, please check.

Comment: do you use windows or mac? i could imagine that the problem ist between systems
Unix uses just a single LF character CHR(10) but Windows expects a CR followed by LF CHR(13)||CHR(10).

Answer (score 0):

if you want the windows line break in your file, you can try the `put` function instead of `put_line`

```
UTL_FILE.PUT (ftype , V_WRITE_TXT || chr(13) || chr(10));
```

The file will look strange on the Linux system.
Good editors (e.g. Notepad ++) can now handle different line breaks